# No route matches error because an instance variable is evaluating to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am stuck in a simple problem. I have a form tag and select tag. On change I want the user to navigate to the chosen category.

This form is available on header and I have defined a change_category action in categories controller.

Here is how it looks : -

application.html.haml

```
=render :partial => "categories/category"
```

categories_controller.rb

```
def change_category
  @categories = Category.all
  @category_name = params[:main]
  @category = Category.find(params[:main])
end
```

_category.html.haml

```
=form_tag(change_category_category_path(@category),:method => "get", :remote => true) do
    =select_tag(:main, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|p| [p.name,p.id]}), :prompt => "Select Category", :onchange => 'this.form.submit();')
```

route.rb

```
resources :categories do
    member do
      get :change_category
    end
  end
```

Error :-

```
No route matches {:action=>"change_category", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil}
```

I think the problem is that @category is evaluating to nil, how can I solve this one?

Comment: Are you setting \@category anywhere? (other than in your change_category) action. Since your header is rendering this snipper everywhere, you need to set \@category on every page.

Comment: so can I do it in application controller? even if I do it in application controller how will it get the id?

Comment: Is the category you want to change to given by @category or what the user picks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you partial is rendered by the layout `@category` may not be set. Furthermore, you can't really know what to set it to, because you want the category that the user changes to to be the one picked in the drop down.

I would make `change_category` a collection action instead (i've also renamed the action to make it read a little nicer):

```
resources :categories do
  collection do
    get :change
  end
end
```

And then your form should change to

```
= form_tag(change_categories_path(),:method => "get", :remote => true) do
  = select_tag(:main, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your routing rules. 
 go to application root directory and type "rake routes" then you can find out your routing rules.

```
 metrics     GET        /metrics(.:format)             metrics#index
             POST       /metrics(.:format)             metrics#create
 new_metric  GET        /metrics/new(.:format)         metrics#new
 edit_metric GET        /metrics/:id/edit(.:format)    metrics#edit
 metric      GET        /metrics/:id(.:format)         metrics#show
             PUT        /metrics/:id(.:format)         metrics#update
             DELETE     /metrics/:id(.:format)         metrics#destroy
```

1. when you generate your routing rules with "resource", it always includes ":id" but you seems doesn't feed it.

solutions 1. make your custom routing rule. you may find a way here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

solution 2. add A "id" input tag in your form to send :id to your controller. and then change "params[:main]" => "params[:id]"